# Fancybox loop:false not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am not a webdev but I tried to get the Fancybox working.
Everything works fine except the loop:false attribute. The pictures don't stopp at the end of the gallery.

Here is my code

> 

```
<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox({'loop': false, });

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
   /*     $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox();*/

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',

        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS: 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick: true,

            openEffect: 'none',


        });
        // Set custom border-width
        $(".fancybox")
            .attr('rel', 'gallery')
            .fancybox({
                padding: 2
            });



    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
    }

    body {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 1250px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    div {
        /*text-align:center;*/
        width: 100%;
    }

    iframe {
        width: 1200px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div>
    <iframe width='800' height='400' frameborder='0' src='/island/island_2015.html' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>



<h3>Simple image gallery</h3>
<p>
    <a class="fancybox" href="/island/img/photoblog/Image01.JPG" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><img src="/island/img/photoblog/thumbs/Image01.JPG" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="/island/img/photoblog/Image02.JPG" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><img src="/island/img/photoblog/thumbs/Image02.JPG" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="fancybox" href="/island/img/photoblog/Image03.JPG" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><img src="/island/img/photoblog/thumbs/Image03.JPG" alt="" /></a>
</p>

<p>
    <a href="www.google.com">ZURÜCK</a>
</p>
```

Does anyone has an idea why the box is not reacting?
thanks for help

Comment: If you meant is not working on IE, then remove the trialing comma after `false` in `'loop': false,` otherwise it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/az9p9gsg/

Comment: Hi JFK, your JSFiddle pointed me to the right track. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it. Had to play a bit in a Sandbox. I had to take the `'loop':false` to this part of the code:

> ```
>         // Set custom border-width
>         $(".fancybox")
>             .attr('rel', 'gallery')
>             .fancybox({
>                 padding: 2,
>                 'loop': false
>             });
> ```

Now working as charme (eventhough got some strange "row" displayed when picture is loading).

Thanks